# Adding a timer to receive iAd Interstitial(Xcode,swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, iad

I have made that when the users click on one button it will show interstitial ad but i do not want like that.I want that if a user use app for 1 minute then it will automatically show ad and after the user close the ad again it come after someTime.

here is the code of mine with button

```
var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var interAdView:UIView = UIView()

 var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close:", forControlEvents:   UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
  }
   func close(sender: UIButton) {
     closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}

func loadAd() {
    println("load Ad")
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = self

}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
  println("ad did load")

    interAdView = UIView()
    interAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.addSubview(interAdView)

    interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}
  func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("ad did not load")
}

   func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("failed to recieve")
    println(error.localizedDescription)

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

@IBAction func ShowAds(sender: UIButton) {
    loadAd()

}
```

Comment: ad will display only for one time when user load app?

Comment: Yup i want something like that @dharmeshkheni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to achieve your requirement.

**First:**

You can use GCD:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 60)   // set delay you time here.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.loadAd()
    })
}
```

**Second:**

You can use `NSTimer`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(60), target: self, selector: "loadAd", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Set repeat parameter to `false` if you don't want to repeat it again.

Comment: Can you explain me the 2nd method ? At what time it will come ?@dharmeshkheni

Comment: After 60 second it will call `loadAd ` method.

Comment: And one more thing i dont want the ad to be appear by clicking on button. I want it to display automatically

Comment: then don't call it in button action method.